# Thank thou or Thank thee

Tags: politeness, grammatical-case, early-modern-english, shakespeare

How would Shakespeare have said "Thank you"? Can't decide if it is *thee* or *thou*, since it isn't really a sentence.

Comment: I believe *thank ye* was one earlier form, sometimes shortened to *thank'ee*. I remember a time when *thank'ee* was commonly used in rural Norfolk - perhaps elsewhere in England too.

Comment: Ye is plural, so that's only if you're thanking more than one person.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker depends on how well you know them.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

On a quick look through the concordance, it appears that Shakespeare rarely wrote *Thank you* and never *Thank thee* without a subject. He often wrote *I thank you* and *we thank you* (and forms such as *to thank thee* and *shall thank thee*); but for a shorter form without a subject he usually used *Thanks*.

*Thank thou* would be ungrammatical, unless it was followed by an object, and would then be a command: *Thank thou the king!*. But there do not seem to be any instances of *thank thou* in his writings.

Comment: *Thank thou* would be grammatical if you were ordering someone to give thanks, which is of course completely the wrong usage case. *Thank thou thy parents for giving thee life!*

Comment: "I thank thee" would have been fine, even he never happened to use it.

Comment: He did, 46 times. I just didn't give it as an example.

Answer (score 28):

From *A Midsummer Night's Dream* Act 5 Scene 1.

> PYRAMUS  Sweet Moon, I thank thee for thy sunny beams.
>
> I thank thee, Moon, for shining now so bright.
>
> For by thy gracious, golden, glittering gleams,
>
> I trust to take of truest Thisbe sight.—

These are of course sentences.

As regards a phrase used in courteous acknowledgement, the OED only has examples for *thank you*. Entering *thank thee* simply gets you back to *thank you*. And it would seem that its use as such was perhaps not in common currency at the time of Shakespeare (died 1616).

The OED provides one example before his time - a *thank yow*

*14..   Why I can't be a Nun 159 in Early Eng. Poems & Lives Saints (1862) 142   ‘Thanke yow, lady’, quod I than.*

But strictly speaking that would appear to be a sentence, not simply a couteous phrase such as we use today - *(I) thank you, lady*

A further example one containing both *you* and *thee* would seem to be subject to the same objection.

*1631   B. Jonson Divell is Asse iv. ii. 21 in Wks. II   Eith. Thanke you good Madame... Tay. Thanke thee, good Eyther-side.*

In short I think the answer to the question is that the simple use of *thank you* for e.g. someone passing you the salt, was probably not around in the sixteenth-century. In any event one could argue that what we say today **is a sentence**. One is in effect saying ***I thank you***.

So to that extent the answer is probably ***I thank thee*** as in the above examples.

Comment: But this doesn't address the question. "Thank you/thou/thee" _not_ "I thank you ..." (note OP's "since it isn't really a sentence").

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Didn't this address the question?
> "In short I think the answer to the question is that **the simple use of *thank you*** for e.g. someone passing you the salt, **was probably *not around* in the sixteenth-century.**"

Comment: According to Colin Fine, no:  'On a quick look through the concordance, it appears that Shakespeare rarely wrote "Thank you" and never "Thank thee" without a subject.' Rarely is not never. //  'Thank you' is a sentence substitute, like 'thanks', 'cheers' or 'ta muchly'. The sentence is a different matter.

Answer (score 16):

Firstly you should realise that the English language was in a state of flux during Shakespeare's time. You will find inconsistencies. Shakespeare's English was not Old English -- it was [Early Modern English](http://www.shakespeare-online.com/biography/shakespearelanguage.html).

1. "Thank you" as used these days is an abbreviation of "I thank you". [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=thank%20you&searchmode=none)
2. Plural form: The modern 'you' is used for both singular and plural. In Shakespeare's day there was a distinction. For example it would make no sense to say "I thank thee" to a group of people. Instead you would have to say "I thank ye" (familiar form) or "I thank you" (polite form).

MACBETH: I thank you, gentlemen. (polite) [Macbeth Act I, scene III](http://www.rhymezone.com/r/gwic.cgi?Path=shakespeare/tragedies/macbeth/i_iii//&Word=of%20the%20imperial%20theme.--i%20thank%20you,%20gentlemen.#w)

KING HENRY VIII: My noble gossips ... I thank ye heartily; so shall this lady. (A king isn't obliged to be polite to his subjects, especially when he is insulting them!)  [King Henry VIII  Act V, scene V](http://www.rhymezone.com/r/gwic.cgi?Path=shakespeare/histories/kinghenryviii/v_v//&Word=i%20thank%20ye%20heartily;%20so%20shall%20this%20lady,#w)

3. Singular form: It is possible to find "I thank you" and "I thank thee" in Shakespeare when spoken to an individual. The explanation is that the plural is used as a sign of respect to an elder or superior. In modern English this respectful form is the only one to survive.

WS2 has given an example of "I thank thee".

CLAUDIO: I thank you, good friend Lucio. (Claudio doesn't have to be so polite to his friend. It's a choice. He is adding a note of respect.)  [Measure For Measure Act I, scene II](http://www.rhymezone.com/r/gwic.cgi?Path=shakespeare/comedies/measureforemeasure/i_ii//&Word=i%20thank%20you,%20good%20friend%20lucio.#w)

4. "Thank thou" is possible for the reason stated by Colin Fine. It would not be a complete utterance and 'thou' would be the subject.

Comment: I was about to "correct" your "I thank you"  vs. "I thank ye" (because as far as I knew, _ye_ is the subject and _you_ the object form), but I thought I'd better check. I find that _I thank ye_ occurs precisely four times in Shakespeare, three of them in _King Henry VIII_, which was co-written with Fletcher. (Apparently Cyrus Hoy used this quirk as one of his diagnostics for separating Shakespeare's and Fletcher's contributions.) So it was a rare form.

Comment: Both 'ye' and 'you' were valid nominative forms in Early Modern English. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye_(pronoun)

Comment: @ColinFine so Fletcher used "ye" and Shakspeare did not?  I am not familiar with King Henry VIII...other plays, I am.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: that is the claim in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_VIII_%28play%29#Authorship), but I have not looked at Hoy's paper to see exactly what he says. Of course Shakespeare used _ye_ as the subject pronoun often - this is about its use as object pronoun in _I thank ye_. There is one instance of this in another Shakespeare play - _As you like it_, so apparently he did use it on this one occasion.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: indeed. _You are_ is far more common in Shakespeare than _ye are_ (only half a dozen instances of the latter). In fact _ye_ is not that common in Shakespeare at all - only 232 instances - and quite a few of them are objective. So its clear that for him _you_ was the normal word in either case, and _ye_ an occasional variant, and my previous comment to michael_timofeev was not quite correct about _ye_.

Comment: @ColinFine Dumb question, but is it possible he used "ye" as a dialect, or to show a person's character?

Comment: @michael_timofeev: it is indeed possible: this occurred to me, but I didn't investigate to see. One reason why I didn't investigate is that I have previously tried to make sense of Shakespeare's use of _thou/thee_ vs _you_, and found that his choice is much less principled than I expected, with characters addressing the same person as both 'thou' and 'you' in the same speech, and even occasionally addressing a servant as 'you'. /

Comment: @ColinFine Of course we are are making the assumption that the folio has Shakespeare's "original" writing.  I think if it did, it would be consistent...just my sense about these things.  Based on the different versions of Hamlet we have, it's hard to say what is original with Shakespeare.

Comment: @ColinFine - Here's a complete shot in the dark about 'you' and 'thou' for the same character. At that time the letter *thorn* was still in existence. It was in the process of being replaced by 'th'.  Also *thorn* had evolved to look very much like a *y*. Is it possible that 'you' was in fact *thou* spelled with an initial thorn? This could be explained by an inconsistency in Shakespeare's own handwriting or be due to the fact that there were different scribes/copyists (not necessarily authors)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter)

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: I don't think the printing convention had anything to do with it. First, it's not just _you/thou_ but other parts of the pronouns as well; secondly thorn was barely in use even in the 15th century, let alone the seventeenth.

Comment: Do you have a link to the research you did? It sounds interesting. I'd like to see your comments on 'other parts of the pronoun'.

Comment: @michael_timofeev Shakespeare's original writing was not necessarily consistent.  He was writing dramatic dialogue.  Different characters speak with different dialects, based on their region and social class.  Even the same character might speak differently depending on register.

Comment: @michael_timofeev in addition, a poet might choose a different word for reasons of rhyme or meter (I am thinking of the Canterbury Tales, where Chaucer uses "sweet" mostly, but "soote" to rhyme with "roote.")

Answer (score 1):

Like the cognate German-Dutch verb "danken", the English verb "thank" requires an object after it, except in making emphasis in imperative mood in Literary English:

> Mr. Brown gave me some food and drinks yesterday. I was happy. I thanked him for helping me.

But in:

> Thank thou thy parents for giving thee life!

(from a comment by Level River St.)

the word "thou" is used for emphasis and is optional as we know that sentences in imperative mood have one of these two understood subjects: you (as singular) or you (as plural), or the archaic version thou and ye respectively.

Comment: Reminds me of the biblical _**Do thou that which is good in thine eyes.**_ (2 Kings 10:5).

Comment: Hello, Rama. But (1) As @chasly says, '[T]he English language was in a state of flux during Shakespeare's time. You will find inconsistencies.' (2) 'Thank thou thy parents' does not correspond to the fragment 'Thank you' (= 'Thanks / Ta // [Cheers]') OP clearly asks about  ('it isn't really a sentence').

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=thanks&allowed_in_frame=0), "thanks" is a shortened form of "I give you thanks".  The "you" in that phrase is the indirect object of the verb.  Therefore, you should use the objective form "thee" rather than the subjective form "thou".

Comment: The question wasn't about _thanks_, but about _thank thee_, which would be grammatically different.

Comment: @ColinFine To spell it out, Thanks> I give thanks to thee > I thank thee > Thank thee.  "Thee is objective" is the real answer here.

Comment: No. _I give thanks to thee_ and _I thank thee_ are different sentences with different structure, which happen to have the same meaning. In particular, _thee_ is the indirect object in the first and the direct object of the second - by early Modern English these were no longer morphologically distinct. _Thee is objective_ is indeed the real answer here, but _I give thanks to thee_ is a red herring.

Comment: @ColinFine Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

On Wikipedia there is an article which might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thou#Declension

In the article it states that 'thou' is the nominative form and 'thee' is the oblique (accusative?) form. I think that if you are giving thanks *to* a person then the oblique form is the correct form.

So my understanding would be that 'I thank thee' is the proper formulation.

Comment: Oblique is both accusative and dative (not to mention any other object case).  Therefore, the oblique form is correct both for "I thank thee" (accusative) and "I give thee thanks" (dative).